# iPhone 11, Unable icloud backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

iPhone 11 Pro Max
Version ios 14.2
Iphone storage used,  65.4GB of 256
iCloud storage used   68.3GB of 200
Previous iphone backed up ok, this shows ¨never¨ backed up.

I have started ¨Back Up now¨ many times, it will start showing estimated time to finish, the line will go to a little over half the lenght but will stop and discontinue backup process.

Have tried reset settings and signing out of icloud and back in.
Good wifi network.

What do I have to do in order for my iphone to finish its backup process?

Comment: We need more details (e.g. tell us the exact iOS version, the latest could be anything in two months), edit your question and don't post comments. Judging by your comment, it sounds like you haven't even waited for the iPhone to finish its backup? Is that even what you want to do (there is **no** question in your post. Also be more specific. Are you using 68.3GB or is that what's free? Did you have an iPhone with iCloud backup enabled before this one, or why are you writing "guess for this iPhone". This is a bad question/post. -1

Comment: I did edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off all things you can in iCloud settings. The idea is to back up as little as possible. Then turn them on half at a time till you discover which “group” is failing.
2. Or, contact Apple support. They can see the logs on the server side and tell what is messed up if needed. You will likely do some other troubleshooting like try a different network, but costumer support has the best tools to support your specific account.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428 ( what iCloud backs up )
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247 ( reduce the size of your backup )